# MinGW: How to upgrade GCC/G++ to version 5 on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, g++, upgrade

I have MinGW installed on my computer and I just found out that my GCC/G++ has problems compiling newer C++ standards. So I want to upgrade from 4.8.1-4 to the latest version (5.3 at the time of writing this).
The MinGW Installation Manager doesn't install a newer version than 4.8.1-4, so I'll probably have to do it somewhat manually. But how? I heard that Cygwin might be able to do it, but I think MinGW and Cygwin would interfere with each other (environment variables). So I'd rather not do it that way.

Comment: The easiest to install is the Nuwen distribution. But it doesn't support encodings. So I use TDM, it works nicely and my version is 5.1.0. Use google. Voting to close as asking for recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

MSYS2 might be a good answer to your needs. It has cygwin-like environment together with mingw3/mingw64 environment. And GCC version is 5.3

Link: https://msys2.github.io/